# Laravel Passport hashed client_id

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I´ve just started Laravel Passport and noticed something weird that has not been in any tutorial. After I run `php artisan passport:install`, it shows my client ID as a long hash. But normally, it should be a clear number.

What have I done wrong?

> root@DESKTOP:/var/www/project/# **php artisan passport:install --force**
> Encryption keys generated successfully. Personal access client created
> successfully. **Client ID: 9b0fd3bd-87ac-4787-a343-0f2b7356d47a** Client
> secret: 3IiDPF5BqG993MESzm9zqjo6rlr6nJbn0wKs3FXv Password grant client
> created successfully. **Client ID: 9b0fd3bd-89c1-441f-b91b-e60775c0d2ad**
> Client secret: 1vGzXHZLNkjEAfxoU6Df14vGg2xS31u56PQxStH0

Comment: In older versions of Laravel Passport, the client ID was an auto-incrementing integer. This changed in Laravel Passport 10 when the client ID was changed to a UUID (Universally Unique Identifier), a long hash-like string.

Comment: @KarlHill thanks!! i was thinking whats wrong with my project :)